# how to convert files with spaces in the names imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

The file path is like `C:\test\NPP\223083-A_BELI Frenchips Poulet roti face.eps`

The command works for files with no spaces in the files name but with spaces it gives me error as below:

> {convert: unable to open image 'C:\test\NPP\223083-A_BELI': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.convert: unable to open image 'Frenchips': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.convert: no decode delegate for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.convert: unable to open image 'Poulet': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.convert: unable to open image 'roti': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.convert: no decode delegate for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.convert: unable to open image 'face.eps': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.convert: invalid argument for option '-resize': C:\test\NPP\EpsTestOutputs\epsToJpg.jpg @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2588.}

**Edit 2: Replacing spaces with %20 in the input file name didn't work, gave me the below error:**

> {convert: unable to open image 'C:\test\NPP\223083-A_BELI%20Frenchips%20Poulet%20roti%20face.eps': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.convert: invalid argument for option **'-resize'**: C:\test\NPP\EpsTestOutputs\epsToJpg.jpg @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2588.}

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any information is required.

Comment: Not a problem with ImageMagick but with the way the Windows shell parses parameters. IIRC you need to put single quotes around the names.

Comment: Use this... `convert "C:\test\NPP\223083-A_BELI Frenchips Poulet roti face.eps" -resize 1024x768 result.jpg`

Comment: Thanks everyone :) My errors for this problem are fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding quotes and passing parameter to resize fixed this issue. 
Final string passed to imagemagick is as below

```
"convert \"C:\\test\\NPP\\223083-A_BELI Frenchips Poulet roti face.eps\" -density 300 -resize 1024x768 C:\\test\\NPP\\EpsTestOutputs\\epsToJpg.jpg"
```

Thanks to everyone who commented on this question. Cheers